# Application crashing when starting an activity from a broadcast receiver, sent from a service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

First of all, I have already tried adding flag_activity_new_task, still its not working.

Here is the flow:
I have a service running that does http request on a background thread and fetches data. Whenever certain data is received, I need to display it to user(for example, an update to the app is available). For this, I use broadcast, and have setup a receiver. Everything works fine till here.

But, when I tru starting an activity from this receiver, app crashes saying:

```
"01-15 17:03:30.129: E/AndroidRuntime(28014): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
"
```

Even though I have added this flag. Here are the codes:

Service part:

```
try
{
    JSONObject mAdDetails = mResult.getJSONObject(Tags.TAG_RPC_SMALL_AD_DETAILS);

    Intent mI = new Intent();
    mI.setAction(ReceiverAdvertSmall.INTENT_ACTION);

    mI.putExtra(AppMapKeys.KEY_AD_HEADING, mAdDetails.getString(Tags.TAG_RPC_AD_HEADING));
    mI.putExtra(AppMapKeys.KEY_AD_DESCRIPTION, mAdDetails.getString(Tags.TAG_RPC_AD_DESCRIPTION));
    mI.putExtra(AppMapKeys.KEY_AD_LINK, mAdDetails.getString(Tags.TAG_RPC_AD_LINK));

    sendBroadcast(mI);

}
catch(JSONException e)
{

}
```

The receiver part:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent data) 
{
    Intent mI = new Intent(mContext, ActivityAdvertSmall.class);

    mI.putExtras(data.getExtras());
    mI.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    mContext.startActivity(data);
}
```

What Am I Doing Wrong? Iam unable to figure it out for last one hour.!!

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use

```
 mContext.startActivity(mI);
```

instead of

```
 mContext.startActivity(data);
```

for start Activity from `onReceive` because you are adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to `mI` intent but trying to start Activity using `data` intent

Answer (score 3):

You should pass the intent you created to `startActivity()`

```
 mContext.startActivity(mI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok....here was the stupidiest mistake I made. I wrongly used `startActivity(data)` instead of `startActivity(mI)`. Closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the intent you created to **startActivity()**

```
 mContext.startActivity(mI);
```